# IPv6 subnetting with different end device requirements

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ipv6, ipv6-transition

`I have three main buildings with building A with 242 end devices, building B with 54 end devices and building C with 894 device. And all the routers are connected to each other like ring topology. The given IP is FC00:abcd:1234::/48. How can I do the subnetting with given parameters please help me. [image: Topology]

Note- the interface between The routers also needed to be subnetted. `

Comment: By the way, you cannot use the `FC00:abcd:1234::/48` prefix. The first half of ULA, `fc00::/8`, is Reserved. The second half, `fd00::/8`, is available for you to use, but you must choose 40 random bits to follow, giving you a relatively unique (remember that the U in ULA means Unique) `/48` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a /64 for every network, don't overthink it. And with a /48 you have more than enough /64's to use one for every network and use one /64 to split into /127's for point to point links.

If you use anything other than a /64 on an IPv6 network, some things (like SLAAC) will not work properly.

Comment: Can you be more specific and give me the full ranges for each network and interface I really need this and this is very imp to me

Comment: I'm not here to do your work. If you do not know how to do IPv6 subnet calculation, I suggest you look into that, so you actually understand what you're doing instead of just copy/pasting someone's suggestions.

Comment: This is starting to feel like a educational/homework question. Please note that these are off topic here.